# Convert hour range to a bitstring

Tags: php, bit-manipulation

I want to save openinghours of a company and I was thinking of using a bitstring for this.
Imagine company A open on monday from 8am until 12(midday) and from 1pm until 5pm would have as bitstring for day 0 (monday)

0000 0000 1111 0111 1000 0000

This makes it very easy to save it in the database and retrieve it without having to do multiple join etc etc.

It does however make it complicated to parse user input to this bitstring.
I want to give the user 2 select lists to select a range where he can choose the opening hour and closing hour (here 8am until midday).
These 2 select lists can then be copied to create a second range (here 1pm until 5pm).

If i could parse one time range to a bitstring (8am until midday), these could then easily be summed up to have the bitstring for one day.

So that is my question. What is the easiest/cleanest way to parse a time range to a bitstring.

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Why not just save it as a DATETIME type?

Comment: How can you save intervals as DATETIME? example: from 11:00->12:00 and 14:00->18:00

Comment: You can't do it in one entry, but you can use two and all works just nice.

Comment: Yeah sure, but what about when there are 3 intervals? or four? I want a solution that works in all cases. These bitstrings do just that

Comment: Then number them. E.g. Columns: `Day`, `Time`, `Order`. Then you can select a full day and order it by the order column

Comment: Quite a lot of the shops around here close at 17:30 - how would your bitstring represent that? A separate table with a foreign key would solve the multiple ranges for one parent record, and would allow you to represent a start and end time nicely

Comment: Indeed, we chose to work by every half hour. Not more then that. I just chose to explain the problem for every hour, because its shorter. The actual bitstring is 48 characters long

Comment: Why not use Unix timestamps?

Comment: Seems like everyone want me to use timestamps/datetime's and save it with extra tables. The reason i'm trying something else is because this would make querying so much easier and faster.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you don't store the bitstring as a string, but rather as an integer. then you perform bitwise comparisons on it, so if you've sliced up a day into 48 parts that means you need to use a 64-bit integer, where the last 16 bits are simply unused, or can be used to represent days of the week.

the bits are as follows

```
/** times **/
01 00:00 02 00:30 03 01:00 04 01:30 05 02:00 06 02:30 07 03:00 08 03:30
09 04:00 10 04:30 11 05:00 12 05:30 13 06:00 14 06:30 15 07:00 16 07:30
17 08:00 18 08:30 19 09:00 20 09:30 21 10:00 22 10:30 23 11:00 24 11:30
25 12:00 26 12:30 27 13:00 28 13:30 29 14:00 30 14:30 31 15:00 32 15:30
33 16:00 34 16:30 35 17:00 36 17:30 37 18:00 38 18:30 39 19:00 40 19:30
41 20:00 42 20:30 43 21:00 44 21:30 45 22:00 46 22:30 47 23:00 48 23:30

49-57 unused

/** days of week **/
58 Sunday 59 Monday 60 Tuesday 61 Wednesday 62 Thursday 63 Friday 64 Saturday
```

Ok so now how do you use this?

If you wanted to say a business was open sunday - saturday 7am to 8am AND 9am to 10am you would add up (using a bitwise OR operator)

take all the "bits" from above and OR them together, this can be accomplished by doing 2 ^ (bit-1)

```
$hours = 2^14 | 2^15 | 2^17 | 2^18 | 2^57 | 2^58 | 2^59 | 2^60 | 2^61 | 2^62 | 2^63;
```

Then do do your querying you simply do a bitwise AND.

```
/** this is checking to see if it's open at 7am and 9am on Thursday **/
$query = (2^14 & 2^17 & 2^61);

/** this will match only if all conditions are true **/
$isOpen = $query & $hours === $query; 

/** this will match if some or all conditions are true **/
$isOpen = $query & $hours > 0;
```

Hopefully this helps you out and puts you on the right path.

Comment: Thanks, this makes sense! Won't this be an issue of overflow? Integers don't go that far

Comment: if you are using a 32-bit system then yes this won't work, however modern systems are 64-bit with a 64-bit OS so there should be no issues.

Comment: in the html you could then simply put
<option value="2">01:00</option>
Parsing the 2 to the correct integer is as simple as 2^2 = 4 = 000..0100
Awesome stuff... In your humble opinion, does this seem like a good way to go? It's like you showed, so easy to check if a company is open at a certain time

Comment: It's definitely an interesting way to deal with hours, I usually use bitwise for days of the week ... but never for times due to the restrictiveness of it (i.e. only 30 minute increments). However if you're fine with the 30 minute blocks then it certainly will work pretty good.